# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onclick'

Tags: jquery, methods, onclick, click

I met some trouble while using Jquery.

I've made some research on google but I did not find any issue since 1 week so I decided to asj the question there  maybe  I'll get more chance for finding an issue.

I have that error while using jquery `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onclick'`

In fact I've first included jquery library in the `<head>...</head>` of my document like that :
`<script src="lib_js/jquery.js"></script>`

then I've written that script seeing some other scripts using jquery (this is the first time I use it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("img.flag").onclick(function()
                {
                    // Get the src of the image
                    var src = $(this).attr("id");

                    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
                    $.post("lib_php/session.php", {"lang": src});
                })
            })
        </script>
```

this script display to me that error on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onclick'
```

I do not know how to fixe that problem.

Anykind of hhelp will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click handler is registered using [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) not `.onclick()` - there is no such method in jQuery API

```
$("img.flag").click(function(){
    // Get the src of the image
    var src = $(this).attr("id");

    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
    $.post("lib_php/session.php", {"lang": src});
})
```